# Allow to use to add an item to model asp.net mvc4

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

**The model:**

```
public class oPage
{
    public int PageId { get; set; }
    public List<oContent> Contents { get; set; }
}
```

The `oContent` object have properties: **Id** and **Text**.

**The view: (Razor)**

```
@for (int i = 0; i <= Model.Agrees.Count; i++)
{
   @Html.TextAreaFor(m => Model.Agrees[i].Text)
}
```

I want to let to user to add another content from the client.

I found some solutions that I don't like:

1. Write the html markup manually. I don't like it because maybe in one day the rendering's structure will change and my code will not word.
   (Like here: http://www.techiesweb.net/asp-net-mvc3-dynamically-added-form-fields-model-binding/)
2. Get the structure from the server. I don't like this because.. well I'm always prefer not use the server unless I have to.
   (Like here: [How to add items to MVC model in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16955101/how-to-add-items-to-mvc-model-in-javascript))

I'm looking for a better and smarter solution.

Comment: I wouldn't agree with your reasoning to not follow those articles.

Comment: Why not? Can you explain please?

Comment: The little DOM manipulation you would be doing with the HTML ie. adding a new table row, I don't see that changing in the foreseeable future as to where it would break your code, that HTML is pretty standard. On your second point, there's nothing wrong with going to Server to add a new item as described in the article

Comment: 1. The problem is not with the manipulation. I want that the same engine that render the "real" items will render the "template".
If from some reason (Update framework or something) the attribute structure will change, than it will be problematic.

2. When I must to going to server I do it. But to get something I can render in the first place, It seems a waste.

Answer (score 0):

The solution a little beat complex but I think that it cover all my points.

The logic is:

1. Get the html from the razor engine

   ```
   @Html.TextAreaFor(m => Model.Agrees[i].Text).ToHtmlString()
   ```
2. Than replace the index number with the attributes name and id (It makes more sense than relying on all attribute value)

   ```
   public static string CreateHelperTemplate(string PlaceholderPerfix, MvcHtmlString mvcHtmlString)
   {
       string Result = "";
       XElement TempNode = XDocument.Parse(mvcHtmlString.ToHtmlString()).Root;

       XAttribute AttrId = TempNode.Attribute("id");
       AttrId.Value = AttrId.Value.Replace("0", PlaceholderPerfix);

       XAttribute AttrName = TempNode.Attribute("name");
       AttrName.Value = AttrName.Value.Replace("0", PlaceholderPerfix);

       // Clear the content if exist
       TempNode.SetValue(string.Empty);

       Result = TempNode.ToString();

       return Result;
   }
   ```
3. The result it something like this:

   ```
   <textarea class="form-control" cols="20" id="Perfix_$__Text" name="Agrees[$].Text" rows="2"></textarea>
   ```

   4. Then, in javascript, when the user click on "Add item" button you can get the "template" and the index and replace the '$' with the index.

So, I not need to call the server and if the structure of the helper will change my code will still work.

It's working.